# How to use AND condition in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have the HTML content as below:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="on" id="radio1" tabindex="0">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="on" id="radio2" tabindex="0">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="on" id="radio3" tabindex="0">
```

Reference:
[How to use OR condition for Keywords in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410321/how-to-use-or-condition-for-keywords-in-robot-framework)

I am currently trying the logic mentioned in above link.But it's not most relevant to my scenario.

I would like to fetch and select the radio button using it's type, name and id or class.

I want to achieve something like below:

**Select Radio Button if //input[@type="radio"] AND //input[name="radioButton"] AND //input[@id="radio2"]**

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an `if` statement. Simply put all of your conditions in a single xpath. For example:

```
select radio button  //input[@type='radio' and @name='radioButton' and @id='radio2']
```

Though, if the id is unique then you don't need all that. If id is unique you can use something like:

```
select radio button //input[@id='radio2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //it can be any driver, not specifically firefox

WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='radioButton' and @id='radio2']");
radioButton.click();
```

The above function will look for the element and click it. And as @Bryan says, if the id is unique you can  look for the element only by its id.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //it can be any driver, not specifically firefox
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.id("@id='radio2']");
radioButton.click();
```